# Dozens of private IP addresses in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, ip-address

I was reviewing my Analytics for the past year and noticed a couple dozen different IP addresses showing up as referrals. I tracked a few of them down to be Google (why are Google IP addresses coming in as referrals?), but there are still quite a handful that come from "private" IP addresses:

`10.x.x.x`

`192.x.x.x`

`172.x.x.x`

for the `10.x.x.x` range of IP addresses, they are all using Port `15871` which I found interesting. I have the company IP address blocked from Analytics, so it shouldn't be any internal visits. Any clue what's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated in [this](http://productforums.google.com/d/msg/analytics/RK4zd_GLpOE/ogtaT8J3f0EJ) Google Product Forums answer, Google Analytic servers cannot see private IP addresses.

It's quite possible that these are [spoofed IP addresses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address_spoofing). Port `15871` by the way is commonly used by Websense's [Web Security and Web Filter](http://www.websense.com/support/article/t-kbarticle/Websense-Web-Security-default-ports), which they may be attempting to exploit.

To exclude internal IP addresses from appearing in your reports, follow the instructions from [this](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034840?hl=en) Google Analytics Help article:

> Create a custom filter to exclude a specific IP address or a range of IP addresses.
>
> *Filter Type*: Custom > Exclude
>
> *Filter Field*: Visitor IP Address
>
> *Filter Pattern*:
>
> - For example, if the single IP address is 176.168.1.1, then enter
>     176.168.1.1.
> - For example, if the range of IP addresses is 176.168.1.1-25 and
>     10.0.0.1-14, then enter ^176.168.1.([1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-5])$|^10.0.0.([1-9]|1[0-4])$
>
> Remember to use [regular expressions](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/answer.py?answer=1034324) to enter an IP address.

You can also use or modify the regex of the code found [here](https://gist.github.com/aronwoost/1000402).

Answer (score 0):

In general, this kind of referrals refers to this situation: when a developer is working on local on a new version of a site, if he clicks on absolute link on a page (when testing), he is redirected to a page which is online. That's why the script of Google Analytics gets this kind of IP address as referrals.

Answer (score 0):

Referrers are just an information the browser sends to the site and you can't rely on them being accurate. So there could be many reasons for that:

- maybe some people are using RSS readers or webmails running in there local networks and linking to your site
- people could just be faking their referrers because they don't want to send the real ones
- development instances of your site running in a local network an linking to your real site